# How to safely import music into rhythmbox in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, music, rhythmbox

I want to import a music folder into Rhythmbox but from the preferences in rhythmbox, the folder has to be of the fixed form,like Artist/Album or Artist/Artist-Album and so on. Why can't rythmbox read the metadata of the mp3 to know the artist, album details and why can't all the music files be present inside a single folder called Music? Why should be there a dependency on the folder name?

Answer (score 3):

According to my use of rhtytmbox you can safely place all the music files into the Music folder in your home directory.the folder hierarchy that your saying is not strictly followed.you can place them any how in the Music folder and Rbox will detect them perfectly.
Also regarding the metadata,Rbox can perfectly detect metadata(if it is there!!).you can also edit the metadata yourself.